# rstudio cannot input chinese

Tags: r, ubuntu

Ubuntu 16.04 Rstudio Can't input Chinese.

My OS all setting done for English. I tried all the methods，including link files、installed qt5、switch fcitx,but all were failed.

Sincerely I want to ask what method can solve this.

Comment: It's locale-dependent, which in R you can get with `Sys.getlocale()` and set with `Sys.setlocale()`. UTF-8 is a good bet, regardless of the language.

Comment: Thank you.This is my result:[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
I should how to solve

Answer (score 0):

```
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL",locale="en_US.UTF-8")
```

You may try your luck with this code. But I think R is not very compatible with other language rather than English. Since the R version I installed in my Chinese OS caused tons of issues.